# UIView backgroundColor with image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, scrollview

I am wondering how I can set the backgroundColor of my UIView to the **scroll View Textured background color**.

this is the way I plan on implementing it but im just not sure what the patternImage is called .

```
jumpBarContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:????]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jumpBarContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]
```

is what you need to use.